# Yarn start run normally but browser not open

Tags: npm, yarnpkg, react-scripts

In the terminal:

```
yarn start
```

The response is:

```
yarn run v1.22.18
$ react-scripts start
Done in 0.15s.
```

Nothing happens, no browser is opened

Other projects in the same machine works fine, with the same Node version and NPM version.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

I found that there is a reserved word that causes the problem.

If the project folder is named "curriculum", or similar, yarn doesn't work.
"Curriculum", "curriculum", "curriculumVitae", none of them work.

To solve it, just rename the folder to any other name, like "Vitae" for example.